# Color chart bars depending on category group value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, bar-chart

I have the following chart (ssrs 2008), it shows sales according to @FromDate and @ToDate parameters. 
The data is correct.
[image]
The problem is that when it shows comparison between years (=more than one year for the same month on a chart), the color stays the same, as you can see in months 4, 5, 6, 7:
[image]

How can i change it? 
I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 2):

There are a few different web descriptions with overviews of controlling the bar colors in a chart, such as [this at learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/formatting-series-colors-on-a-chart-report-builder-and-ssrs) or [Change the series colors for a bar chart](http://www.bidn.com/blogs/mikedavis/ssis/488/ssrs-2008-change-the-series-colors-for-chart-and-legend) (Images are currently dead in this, limiting its helpfulness).

The key is finding the "Series Properties" dialog and the "Fill" section, where you can specify the fill color: Use an expression such as:

```
=IIF(YEAR(Fields!MyDateField.Value) mod 2 = 0, "#FF0000", "#00FF00")
```

Comment: I'd possibly remove that link. All the images from that blog have died making it difficult to follow

Answer (score 1):

To Add some more explanation to JamieFs answer. This is the steps that I followed:

Right click on the series Select "Series Properites..."

[image]

Go to Fill:

[image]

Press the Expression button(`Fx`) and type in your equation to calculate the colour:

[image]